# Label and ref for a chart

Tags: tikz-pgf

I have a chart like this one shown below. I want put a caption with the number of the graph and the put a \label to refer to the graph in the way that when i use \ref{} the number of the graph is shown.

```
\begin{center}
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale = 1]
\begin{axis}[
x filter/.code=\pgfmathparse{#1 },
]
\addplot table {

   5 25
   10 100
   15 225
   20 400
   25 625
   30 900

};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{center}
```

Someone can explain how can I do? Because I receive an error.

Comment: Do you want it to float?   Do you want it to be a figure, or a new float type (e.g. `chart`)?

Comment: ..." I receive an error". Please tell us more about this error. (The code snippet you've posted doesn't produce an error, does it?)

Comment: @Mico I tried to put \label after tikzpicture, but after the use of \ref I receive the reference to the section not to the chart. Then i put \label after axis to see if it works, but i received the error "Can't create label..."

Comment: @Bernard I'd like to have a new float type, in this way I will have an enumeration just for charts.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I give details on  what @Mico added: new float type, list of charts and `cleveref configuration`:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{amstext}
\usepackage{ pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.14}
\usepackage{caption, float}
\floatstyle{plaintop}
\newfloat{chart}{tbph}{loc}
\floatname{chart}{Chart}
\usepackage{cleveref}
\crefname{chart}{chart}{charts}
\Crefname{chart}{Chart}{Charts}
\newcommand\listofcharts{\listof{chart}{List of Charts}}

\begin{document}

\listofcharts
\vspace{8\baselineskip}
\begin{chart}
  \centering
  \begin{tikzpicture}[scale = 1]
    \begin{axis}[
        x filter/.code=\pgfmathparse{#1 },
      ]
      \addplot table {

        5 25
        10 100
        15 225
        20 400
        25 625
        30 900

      };
    \end{axis}
  \end{tikzpicture}
  \caption{A chart test}\label{ch-test}
\end{chart}

We see from \cref{ch-test} …

\Cref{ch-test} shows us …

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

LaTeX's label-ref cross-referencing system requires (through clever behind-the-scenes) work that the argument of `\label` be associated with the most-recently-incremented counter variable. E.g., in

```
\section{Hello World} \label{sec:hello}
```

the string `sec:hello` is associated by LaTeX with the counter called `section`. Aside: Not just any counter incrementing method will do. Usually, the counter has to be incremented through `\refstepcounter`. Sure enough, LaTeX employs a call to `\refstepcounter{section}` while executing the code associated with `\section`.

In the case of your code snippet, observe that no counter is associated with the `tikzpicture` environment. Thus, if you do provide an instruction such as `\label{mypic}`, LaTeX has no alternative but to associate `mypic` with the most-recently-incremented counter, which (in the case of your document) appears to be the `section` counter.

Clearly, that's not your intent. What to do? I suggest you (a) place the entire `tikzpicture` environment in a `figure` environment, (b) create a caption via a `\caption` statement, and (c) provide a `\label` instruction -- `\label{mypic}` would be entirely OK -- *after* the `\caption` statement. (Aside: the `\caption` statement, when used inside a `figure` environment, increments a counter called `figure`. I know, not exactly imaginative...)

---

*Addendum*: I just noticed a comment you directed at @Bernard, about possibly creating a new, dedicated float type. To create a new float type, called (say) `chart`, you could proceed as follows:

- Load the [float](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/float/) package
- Issue the instruction

  ```
  \newfloat{chart}{tbhp}{crt}
  ```

  after loading the `float` package. This sets up a floating environment called, you guessed it, "chart" and a counter variable called "chart" as well.
- Encase your `tikzpicture` environments in `chart` environments, and use `\caption` statements as you would in `figure` and `table` environment. Then use `\label` and `\ref` as you would with other items in a LaTeX document.